# How can I add a symbol after a set amount of words in Word? (Or any other program)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, formatting

So I have this huge list of words that are unordered in any way. All formatted the same way. They're all just words like in the example below:

"Word1"

"Word2"

"Word3"

Now I need to put a symbol after every 30 or so words, but how can I do this? My brain is grinding on how to do this but I have no clue anymore. I am hoping you can help... It doesn't necesarily have to be in word (or perhaps in Excel or so?), but it would be the most convenient.

**The problem here is is that at the start of the 30 words, I need this symbol { , and at the end of the thirty words I need this symbol } . How can I do this?**

It's impossible to do this manually since it is a huge 200k+ word list...

Honestly I have no clue anymore. Also, I tried to use the replace function in Word but yeah, it does not have an 'Amount of words' function.. Clueless

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is continuous text or are there carriage returns? What about tags?

Comment: Honestly I have no clue anymore. Also, I tried to use the replace function in Word but yeah, it does not have an 'Amount of words' function.. Clueless

Comment: Have you tried a regular expression? Something like `(\w+\s){30,30}` might work. Also, please don't add info in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1336831/edit) you question instead

Comment: Thank you I will edit my original post. I just tried what you said but it tells me there is none found. I have used the 'Replace' tab for this and typed in what you gave me and tried replacing

Comment: MS Word doesn't support Regex, try with EmEditor, Notepad++, or another good text editor. If you're unfamiliar with Regex, you can text your search pattern [here](https://regex101.com/) (I just did mine and it works)

Comment: I tried it in notepad++ and it says 0 occurrences were replaced :(. Even though I also tried it on the site you mentioned and it seems to work there...

Comment: Anyone?????????

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `(\w+\s){30,30}` in Notepad++:

[image]

(In the above example, I inserted `###` at the end of the pattern)

Comment: I think the issue may be that my words are 1 per 'line' instead of all on one line (and so I have close to 300k lines). Still that should give me at least one result if that were the case. Instead it cant find anything for me.                                      
           Edit: Nah this cant be it as in the tester it works too..

Comment: Here is the image of the replace window https://imgur.com/J9EBTYN

Comment: Even if it works, it doesn't do what I'd like it to right? I need the { at the beginning and } at the end

Comment: I did ask at the beginning if there were carriage returns... Regex doesn't play as nice as it should with those. In Word, with Wildcards turned on, use the following pattern: `*^013` (repeated 30 times) and replace with `{^&}`

Comment: But there are no returns yet, that's what I need to create in there. Idk if that's what you meant also

Comment: I just tried what you said, but that doesn't do what I want to do at all. It needs to be per 30 words... Not per word

Comment: The information you are giving is contradictory or incomplete. At this point all I can do is ask you to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1336831/edit) you question with sample data.